# Stop a navigation request in Casper JS

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

I am trying to scrape a website using casper and when a page is loaded, I see there are a lot of navigation requests with `isMainFrame = false`. I guess that these are ads. An example from verbose logs -

```
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://static.licdn.com/scds/common/u/lib/inject/0.4.2/relay.html?swf=https://static.licdn.com/scds/common/u/lib/inject/0.4.2/relay.swf&xdm_e=https://www.linkedin.com&xdm_c=default3784&xdm_p=1, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=false
```

This is really slowing the script down and I do not want casper to spend time on fetching / navigating to these URLs.

To stop these I guess I will have to catch the event `navigation.requested` and stop it there. But I am not sure how to stop the navigation.

I guess I will have to do something like this -

```
casper.on 'navigation.requested', (url, navigationType, navigationLocked, isMainFrame) ->
      if not isMainFrame
         //stop this navigation
      else
        //proceed normally
```

Any idea how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Explored the sources.

Looks like you can't do it at the moment without patching.

What you *can* do is to add an entry in the `hosts` file so that this request will finish very fast.